# NetLogo - Sandpile - Error

Tags: syntax-error, netlogo

I am chasing my tail with this piece if code.  Having rectified one error (with the help of stakoverflow) i now get another.  The error reports "TASK expected 1 input, a reporter or task command" and highlights the word "task".  I am not sure if it to do with the brackets?

```
;; The density of patches to be set with a random value is set using variable init-errors on interface.
;; Every patch uses a task which reports a random value.
;; The random value is set using variable error-count on interface
to setup-random
   ask patches [
     if (random-float 100.0) < init-errors
        [ setup task ] [ random error-count ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `setup task [ random error-count ]`, so that you're passing the reporter block `[ random error-count ]` to `task`. So the whole thing would look like:

```
to setup-random
   ask patches [
     if (random-float 100.0) < init-errors
        [ setup task [ random error-count ] ]
```

The above assumed that `setup` was a procedure runnable by patches. If this is actually just a modification of the sandpile model in the models library, then you probably want:

```
to setup-random
   setup task [
     ifelse-value (random-float 100.0 < init-errors) [
       random error-count
     ] [
       0 ;; Or whatever you want your non-"error" patches to get.
     ]
   ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces a further error stating "you can't use SETUP in a patch context, because SETUP is observer only".  The error highlight "setup"?